# Hadoop Reducer can't handle nested loop computations?

Tags: hadoop, for-loop, join, mapreduce, nested-loops

I am trying to perform a join by simply finding matches using the following nested loop (below). The job runs fine on smaller data sets but gets stuck on larger data sets. It goes through reducer till it reaches 99% or 98% and just hangs. I don't know if it is a memory issue or the reducers just cant handle the for loops computation when it exceeds a certain amount of records. I would like to note that if I leave out the for loops part of the code the job finishes on the larger data sets.

```
public void reduce (Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
String kjoin=key.toString();
String result="";
List<String[]> tGrad = new ArrayList<String[]>();
List<String[]> tUni = new ArrayList<String[]>();
List<String[]> tDep = new ArrayList<String[]>();
List<String[]> memOf = new ArrayList<String[]>();
List<String[]> subOrg = new ArrayList<String[]>();
List<String[]> ungrad = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String line="";
String source="";
int i=0;

for (Text value : values){
line=value.toString();
String[] parts=new String[2];

source=line.substring(0,line.indexOf(","));
// everything before the first comma. 
parts[0]=line.substring(line.indexOf(",")+1,line.lastIndexOf(","));
// between first comma and last.
parts[1]=line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(",")+1);
// after last comma 

//separate components 

    if (source.equals("tGrad")){
        tGrad.add(parts);


        }  else if (source.equals("tUni")) {
            tUni.add(parts);


            } else if (source.equals("tDep")){
                tDep.add(parts);

                    }else if (source.equals("memOf")){
                        memOf.add(parts);

                        }  else if (source.equals("subOrg")) {
                                subOrg.add(parts);

                                } else if (source.equals("ungrad")){
                                    ungrad.add(parts);

                    }//end if/else  



source=null;
line=null;
} // end for loop for iteration over values.



//join tuples
 for (String[] so: subOrg){ 

    for (String[] mo: memOf){ 
    if (so[0].equals(mo[1])){ 
        for (String[] ug: ungrad){
        if (so[1].equals(ug[1]) && mo[0].equals(ug[0])){  
            for (String[] tu: tUni){
                if (ug[1].equals(tu[0]) ){
                for (String[] td: tDep){
                    if (mo[1].equals(td[0])){
                    for (String[] tg: tGrad){
                    if (mo[0].equals(tg[0])){



    result="f("+td[0]+","+mo[0]+","+mo[1]+","+so[0]+","+so[1]+","+tu[0]+","+ug[0]+ug[1]+tg[0]+","+")";
    context.write(NullWritable.get(),new Text(result)); /
                    } //end 1st if
                } // end 2nd if

            } // end for
        } // end for 
    } //end for  

    }
}
}
  }}    
    }//end method   
 }//end class
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not due memory or limitation of reducer but its due to the way you are doing computation.It will be good if you define your join computation using map reduce instead of doing all the computation inside a single reducer.If you run the same computation in standalone code you will see the same issue.Please go through this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/869383/Implementing-Join-in-Hadoop-Map-Reduce) to understand how you can do joins in mapreduce

Comment: thanx for the reply, your right. But i am performing a multiway join and I would prefer that it is processed in a single reducer otherwise I would need to break it down to several intermediate two way joins and therefor require multiple jobs.